# Launch Jade agents using swing

Tags: java, swing, agents-jade

i have coded a database update software which allows me to deploy a jade mobile agent in order to update the database.  In order for it to run, i need to launch it using the AMS gui.  I wanted to be able to launch it from gui.  I have now done a nice swing gui and i only need to know the code which allows me to launch my mobile agent when the "Update" button is clicked.  What is the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To launch an agent or do whatever related to JADE you need to write YOUR code using JADE libraries and API, irrespective of what Front End you have used (Swing in this case)
One suggestion would be, to keep the modularity, is create another file which does one of many such operations you want, and let your Swing GUI interact (say via sockets) to that file, triggering your operation.
That file, which would act as a server, would listen to the front end and do the respective work. But all commands are to be coded using JADE API. One such code is:

`ContainerController cc = Runtime.instance().createAgentContainer(newProfileImpl());`

``` Object arguments[] = new Object[1];``arguments[0]=new Object(); ```

`AgentController dummy = cc.createNewAgent("mob2","mobiletrial", arguments);`

`dummy.start();`

Comment: What I've done in the past is create a "Coordinator Agent" that launches other agents. The coordinator is typically accessed using a swing and interface via bools (instead of sockets).

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I wrote for launching one agent from another.You'll have to edit it for multiple container use.

```
void launchAgent( final String AgentName, final String AgentType)
{
    log(Level.FINER,"attempting to launch angent name: "+AgentName+" type: "+AgentType);
    CreateAgent ca = new CreateAgent();
    ca.setAgentName(AgentName);
    ca.setClassName(AgentType);
    ca.setContainer(new ContainerID(AgentContainer.MAIN_CONTAINER_NAME, null));
    Action actExpr = new Action(this.getAMS(), ca);
    ACLMessage request = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
    request.addReceiver(this.getAMS());

    request.setOntology(JADEManagementOntology.getInstance().getName());


    request.setLanguage(FIPANames.ContentLanguage.FIPA_SL);
    request.setProtocol(FIPANames.InteractionProtocol.FIPA_REQUEST);
    try {
        getContentManager().fillContent(request, actExpr);

        addBehaviour(new AchieveREInitiator(this, request) {
            protected void handleInform(ACLMessage inform) {
            log(Level.INFO,"Agent successfully created name:"+AgentName+" type: "+AgentType);
            }

        protected void handleFailure(ACLMessage failure) {
            log(Level.SEVERE,"Agent launch failed name: "+AgentName+" type: "+AgentType);
            }
            } );
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```